# Turning list to svm input

Tags: python, dataset, scikit-learn, svm

I am implementing an svm model with python and scikit learn. I have reached to a point where I have selected and transformed my features and merged them to a list  that looks like this:

```
[[17, 14, 14, 7, 14, 14, 14, 7, 14, 14, 1], 
 [14, 14, 7, 14, 14, 14, 7, 14, 14, 7, 1], 
 [14, 7, 14, 14, 14, 7, 14, 14, 7, 14, 1], 
 [7, 14, 14, 14, 7, 14, 14, 7, 14, 7, 1], 
 [14, 14, 14, 7, 14, 14, 7, 14, 7, 14, 1], 
 [14, 14, 7, 14, 14, 7, 14, 7, 14, 7, 1], 
 [14, 7, 14, 14, 7, 14, 7, 14, 7, 13, 1], 
 [7, 14, 14, 7, 14, 7, 14, 7, 13, 7, 1], 
 [14, 14, 7, 14, 7, 14, 7, 13, 7, 14, 1], 
 [14, 7, 14, 7, 14, 7, 13, 7, 14, 10, 1], 
 [7, 14, 7, 14, 7, 13, 7, 14, 10, 4, 1], 
 [14, 7, 14, 7, 13, 7, 14, 10, 4, 13, 1], 
 [7, 14, 7, 13, 7, 14, 10, 4, 13, 13, 1], 
 [14, 7, 13, 7, 14, 10, 4, 13, 13, 7, 1], 
 [7, 13, 7, 14, 10, 4, 13, 13, 7, 13, 1], 
 [13, 7, 14, 10, 4, 13, 13, 7, 13, 3, 1], 
 [7, 14, 10, 4, 13, 13, 7, 13, 3, 13, 1], 
 [14, 10, 4, 13, 13, 7, 13, 3, 13, 13, 1], 
 [10, 4, 13, 13, 7, 13, 3, 13, 13, 3, 1], 
 [4, 13, 13, 7, 13, 3, 13, 13, 3, 13, 0], 
 [13, 13, 7, 13, 3, 13, 13, 3, 13, 13, 0], 
 [13, 7, 13, 3, 13, 13, 3, 13, 13, 14, 0]]
```

The last number in each tuple is the label. I am trying to find a way to create a dataset that could separate the data and the target in order to build a model. I couldn't find anything similar in the documentation. Will it be easier to turn it back to Dataframe?

Thank you!

Comment: ```import numpy as np``` + ```data = np.array(my_list)``` + ```X = data[:, :-1]``` + ```Y = data[:, -1]``` is enough if your description/assumption about the current form is true. That's basic numpy stuff. Consider the numpy-docs tutorial on how to process arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean separate the features from the labels? If so, you can use numpy.

```
from sklearn import svm
import numpy as np
data = np.asarray(A)
X = data[:,:-1]
y = data[:,-1]
clf = svm.SVC()
clf.fit(X, y)
```

A is the original data list.

Comment: I think it should be array, I have fixed the answer, thanks